# how to change dataframe in apply functions pandas

Tags: pandas, apply

I want to use apply to dynamically modify the content of my dataframe, the table is like:

```
   index  price signal  stoploss
0      0   1000   True     990.0
1      1   1010  False     990.0
2      2   1020   True    1010.0
3      3   1000  False    1010.0
4      4    990  False    1010.0
5      5    980  False    1010.0
6      6   1000  False    1010.0
7      7   1020   True    1010.0
8      8   1030  False    1010.0
9      9   1040  False    1010.0
```

my code is :

```
def test(row, dd):
    if row.signal:
        dd['inorder']=True
        row['stoploss']=1

    df = pd.DataFrame({'index':[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
                   'price':[1000,1010,1020,1000,990,980,1000,1020,1030,1040],
                   'signal':[True, False, True, False, False, False, False, True, False, False]})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    df['stoploss'] = df.loc[df['signal'], 'price'] - 10
    df['stoploss'].ffill(inplace=True)


    xx = dict(inorder=False)
    df.apply(lambda row: test(row, xx), axis=1)
    print(df)
```

When I trace into the function test, I can see that the value is indeed changed to 1, but out of the function test scope, it seems has no effect on the dataframe.

I tried to the use another way to modify the content of the dataframe,

```
for k, row in df.iterrows():
    if row.signal:
        xx['inorder'] = True
        df.loc[k, 'stoploss'] = 1
```

this one works, but obviously it's a lot slower than apply.

The correct result I expect is :

```
   index  price signal  stoploss
0      0   1000   True       1.0
1      1   1010  False     990.0
2      2   1020   True       1.0
3      3   1000  False    1010.0
4      4    990  False    1010.0
5      5    980  False    1010.0
6      6   1000  False    1010.0
7      7   1020   True       1.0
8      8   1030  False    1010.0
9      9   1040  False    1010.0
```

How to achieve that assignment in apply please?

Thanks

Comment: use: `df.stoploss=np.where(df.signal,1,df.stoploss)` , apply is not needed for this purpose

Comment: My actual requirement is much complicated that's why I just use a simple example here. It seems that I add return row in test. And df = df.apply will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the docs for [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), you'll notice that `apply` does not change the DataFrame in place, but rather returns a new dataframe where the function has been applied.

So, in your seconds to last line, you can try

```py
df = df.apply(lambda row: test(row, xx), axis=1)
```

**Edit:**

IMO, this isn't very well documented, but the call
`df.apply(func, axis=1)` will apply `func` to each row, and *set the row to the return value of `func`*.

As written, your example won't work because the function you're applying doesn't return anything.  The following minimal example works the way you intend.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'index':[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
                   'price':[1000,1010,1020,1000,990,980,1000,1020,1030,1040],
                   'signal':[True, False, True, False, False, False, False, True, False, False]})

df['stoploss'] = df.loc[df['signal'], 'price'] - 10
df['stoploss'].ffill(inplace=True)

def test(row):
    row.stoploss = 1 if row.signal else row.stoploss
    return row

modified_df = df.apply(test, axis=1)
```

---

As an aside, I don't think you actually need to use `apply` to get the result you want.  Have you tried something like

```py
df.loc[df['signal'] == True, 'stoploss'] = 1
```

That would be a much simpler and faster way to get your target output.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is just a simple illustration of the function. The function I really need is much more complicated than the example. Thanks why I need to use apply.

Comment: I tried df = df.apply..., but it seems to be wrong, only give me a number of None. Not the correct dataframe

Comment: Oops, I forgot to mention that the function you pass to `apply` needs to return the row.  I edited my answer